# Gerrit change appears in both merged and in outgoing reviews

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a `Gerrit` change which on my gerrit changes show as `Outgoing reviews`, but upon going to that particular change gerrit shows the same as `Change 1313201 - Merged`.

The code review and auto commit validations are done for this change and are already in approved state.

Need help on how to clear this change of my `Outgoing reviews` list.

Comment: We once encountered the same issue. It was caused by Lucene's IndexWriter exception.We restarted gerrit and it was then okay.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to reindex the change on Lucene:

```
curl -s --request POST --user GERRIT-USERNAME https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/1313201/index
```

Comment: What should be the value of `USER`.

Comment: I tried the above command by replacing `USER` with my `git config user.name` value. It asked for a password,  provided my gerrit account password for the same. It did not flush out the merged change from my outgoing reviews.

Comment: The USER is the Gerrit username you use to sign in to Gerrit. I just changed USER to GERRIT-USERNAME in the answer. Are you sure your command executed successfully?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This answer solves our problem perfectly. Our gerrit has some changes that are stuck in outgoing reviews while all of them are already submitted. The result of gerrit-query shows they are new and open. After running this restapi for each change, all have become normal now. The command is a bit different, `curl --digest -X POST --user ${username}:${httpassword} http://${host}/gerrit/a/changes/${change}/index`.